# SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error

Tags: hdparm

I'm having problems with a 2TB drive being visible as a 1TB drive in the BIOS. A little research suggests this is due to HPA.

I have booted off a live-CD. The syslog contains the following:

```
[    2.800165] ata3.00: HPA unlocked: 3907027055 -> 3907029168, native 3907029168
```

I tried using `hdparm`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 max sectors   = 3907029168/14715056(18446744073321613488?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -N p3907029168 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting max visible sectors to 3907029168 (permanent)
 SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error
 max sectors   = 3907029168/14715056(18446744073321613488?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

And I'm now out of ideas. What can I do to remove the HPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that although it said that it failed, it may have succeeded. Upon rebooting into the BIOS, the full capacity of the drive was visible.